# UITableViewCell accessory views affecting each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I have a very weird problem where one `UITableViewCell`'s accessory view seems to affect the frame of another `UITableViewCell`'s accessory view.

When I run the app, it looks like this at first (The slider and the +/– buttons are contained in a plain `UIView` which is set as the table view cell's accessory view.):

[image]

After reloading the table view, however, the slider gets resized to look like this (It's too wide now, reaching under the '+' button.):

[image]

This only seems to happen when I add a `UISwitch` as an accessory view to the last row of the table view!? I absolutely don't get how one row's accessory view could be able to affect (through autoresizing?) the width of a subview of another row's accessory view.

I believe when I used this kind of code in an app the last time, this glitch wasn't present. That was about two to three years ago, with Xcode 11.3.1 on macOS 10.14 with a deployment target of iOS 8. Now I'm on Xcode 14.2 on macOS 12.6.2 with a deployment target of iOS 13.

I tried to narrow down the error in order to get a reasonable minimal example, but it's still somewhat lengthy, so sorry for that.

I create a new iOS app in Xcode and throw away the storyboard. My code looks like so:

```
// AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
}

@end
```

```
// AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    TableViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleInsetGrouped];
    
    UINavigationController *navController =
        [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
    
    [window setRootViewController:navController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}

@end
```

```
// TableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    UIView *sliderContainerView;
}

@end
```

```
// TableViewController.m

#import "TableViewController.h"

static NSString *const kDefaultCell = @"DefaultCell";

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Title"];
    
    UIBarButtonItem *reloadButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"reloadData" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(reloadAction:)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:reloadButtonItem];
    
    // create the slider container view
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 7); // actual width is not important, will get updated before display
    sliderContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    
    UIFont *buttonFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40 weight:UIFontWeightThin];
    
    // create the minus button
    frame = CGRectMake(0, -29, 0, 0);
    UIButton *minusButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [minusButton setFrame:frame];
    [minusButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
    [minusButton setTitle:@"–" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[minusButton titleLabel] setFont:buttonFont];
    [minusButton sizeToFit];
    [sliderContainerView addSubview:minusButton];
    
    // create the slider
    frame = CGRectMake(34, 0, 82, 7);
    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [slider setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    slider.minimumValue = 1;
    slider.maximumValue = 10;
    [sliderContainerView addSubview:slider];
    
    // create the plus button
    frame = CGRectMake(120, -29, 0, 0);
    UIButton *plusButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [plusButton setFrame:frame];
    [plusButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [plusButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[plusButton titleLabel] setFont:buttonFont];
    [plusButton sizeToFit];
    [sliderContainerView addSubview:plusButton];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    
    [self updateLengthViewWidth];
}

- (void)updateLengthViewWidth
{
    UITableView *tableView = [self tableView];
    int lengthViewWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - [tableView layoutMargins].left - [tableView layoutMargins].right - 128;
    
    CGRect frame = [sliderContainerView frame];
    frame.size.width = lengthViewWidth;
    [sliderContainerView setFrame:frame];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDefaultCell];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kDefaultCell];
        
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:@"foo"];
        [cell setAccessoryView:sliderContainerView];
    } else if ([indexPath row] == 1) {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:@"bar"];
        [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
    } else if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:@"baz"];
        [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
    } else if ([indexPath row] == 3) {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:@"baz"];
        [cell setAccessoryView:[[UISwitch alloc] init]];
    }
    
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)reloadAction:(id)sender
{
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

@end
```

Any idea what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest creating a custom view class that contains the slider and two buttons and set it all up to use constraints. If you get to the point where you are getting the screen size then you are doing it all wrong. Constraints are so much better. As a side note you seem to be writing your Objective-C code with a 15 year old style. Time to start using modern syntax. So much easier.

Comment: You're right, the coding style is a bit ancient. That's because the rest of the codebase which I extracted this snippet from looks like this as well. (I just converted the code to ARC for the example …) Plus, I personally don't like the mix of dot notation and bracket-style method calls in "modern" Objective-C, so I tend to avoid it altogether.
You're of course right in that using the screen size is a bad idea. However, the code used to work like this for the past ten years and I didn't want to completely rework it (and wrap my head around Auto Layout) … well, maybe the time has come.

Comment: So I ended up replacing the current implementation with a UITableViewCell subclass. Quite a lot of effort for fixing such a tiny bug, but what can you do …